# С++ файл должен открывать сам себя

Tags: c++, файлы, файловая-система

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при определённых условиях программа открывала саму себя в новом окне. Получается сделать через указание полного пути к файлу - `system("start C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\C++\\Project5\\Debug\\Project5.exe");`
Как сделать, чтобы файл мог открываться, не зная полный путь (или узнавать его и идти по нему), чтобы программу могли использовать на других устройствах?

Comment: Анализируйте первый элемент второго аргумента в  `int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {...`

Comment: а под линуксом можно использовать fork и компанию.

Answer (score 1):

Функция `main` имеет вид

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

Элемент `argv[0]` во всех *приличных* компиляторах представляет собой полный путь к самой программе...

Comment: `argv[0]` зависит скорее от ОС. Если память не изменяет, на линуксе туда можно передать произвольную строку...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Передавать можно. Но по умолчанию работает и тут - https://ideone.com/SyFd7J